# Identifying oldest thread in java stack trace

Tags: java, jboss, stack-trace

I am examining a Java thread dump, from when part of my application (deployed on JBoss 4.2.3) had locked up due to blocking database queries. There are 6 threads all of which are executing various queries and I want to identify which was the first to execute as this will be a candidate for the initial cause.

Can I compare the Total CPU time and User Time on each thread and treat the thread with the highest time as the oldest (the first to run)? Or might different threads be allocated different amounts of time?

E.g (simple example)

```
Thread ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-19 (Id = 21) RUNNABLE 
  Total CPU time 100000 ms, User time 100000 ms 

  stack here...

 Thread ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-19 (Id = 200) RUNNABLE 
  Total CPU time 200000 ms, User time 200000 ms 

  stack here...

Thread ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-19 (Id = 2590) RUNNABLE 
  Total CPU time 300000 ms, User time 300000 ms  < --- THIS THREAD MUST HAVE STARTED BEFORE OTHERS

  stack here...
```

Comment: You can consider using a thread dump analyser such as
http://mchr3k.github.com/javathreaddumpanalyser/
 or 
http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure if that adds the information I require (if it's not already there in the Total CPU time/Total User time)

Comment: Total CPU time or Total User time does not give you any info on the age of the thread. It can only say that the the thread age at the minimum is this value.

Comment: Thanks @NandakishoreK - do you want to post that as answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total CPU time or Total User time does not give you any info on the age of the thread. It can only say that the the thread age at the minimum is this value.

You can consider using a thread dump analyser such as [Mchr3k - Java Thread Dump Analyser](http://mchr3k.github.com/javathreaddumpanalyser) or [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html)

Comment: Out of interest - when would the situation occur that thread A was older than thread B, but thread A had a higher CPU/User time?

Comment: That depends on the scheduler. If thread A was more CPU bound and thread B was more I/O bound, then the scheduler might heuristically decide that thread A needs more CPU time, and hence its CPU time would be higher.